# Missing permissions for echoing something via shell_exec()

Tags: shell, permissions, php, non-root-user

I want to use the PHP `shell_exec()` function in order to send something to a local socket.

My current approach looks like this:

```
sudo -s echo "foobar" > /dev/tcp/192.168.178.41/8080
```

**When I run this command in the commandline, everything works perfectly**. However, when I try to execute this in a PHP script, **nothing happens**.

There's not even an error in `/var/log/httpd/apache24-error_log`. (Yep, that's the right path.)

**I'm using a Synology Diskstation with it's linux-like OS.**

## My Investigation:

- I ran `echo exec("whoami");`. It returned `http`. Aparently, the apache user is called `http`.
- I than modified the `/etc/sudoers` file, in order to grant the user all the needed permissions. My linux distro has no `visudo`, so I had to edit it manually. It now looks like this:

  ```
  # Enable logging of a command's output.
  # Use sudoreplay to play back logged sessions.
  Defaults syslog=authpriv

  # Allow root to execute any command
  root ALL=(ALL) ALL

  # Allow members of group administrators to execute any command
  %administrators ALL=(ALL) ALL

  # Configure privilege of wheel group
  Cmnd_Alias SHELL = /bin/ash, /bin/sh, /bin/bash
  Cmnd_Alias SU = /usr/bin/su
  %wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL, !SHELL, !SU

  http ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/sudo, /bin/echo, /usr/bin/sudo, /usr/bin/echo
  ```

How can I succesfully run this command using PHP?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is PHP's `shell_exec()` actually calling `bash` or instead some other `sh` ? Also why are you using `sudo` to echo a string?

Comment: @thrig I just tried out using `sudo`, I read that online. I'm gonna try to leave it out.

Comment: @AndyDalton So do you think this has something to do with the writing permissions? Because otherwise, this would clearly not be a dupe.

Comment: @thrig Wow. Even though I didn't expect that, it worked when not using `sudo`. Make it an answer and take that rep :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did an experiment, and `shell_exec()` is using `sh`, as @thrig suspected in his comment above.  On your Synology Diskstation, `/bin/sh` might not be realized using `bash` (or something that supports `/dev/tcp/...`).

A variation of this seems to work for me:

```
shell_exec("bash -c 'echo foobar > /dev/tcp/192.168.178.41/8080'")
```